# Add equation to OpenXML in Professional format( unicodemath to omml converter )

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using OpenXML to create a Word processing document and add equations. When pasting an equation into officeMath text in unicodemath("F_d=γ_c (γ_(R,R) RA+ u∑▒〖γ_(R,f) f_i h_i 〗) ") format, the equation is pasted in linear format.I need a professional format. To insert an equation in professional format, you need to convert the equation to OMML.
Is there a converter from unicodemath to omml code?